# CPU frequency scaling stuck 2.80 Ghz and it's not going down

Tags: 16.04, cpu, cpufreq

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with gnome desktop. I set the governor to "ondemand", but the CPU still runs at top frequency.

I tried many things, but it's stuck at 2.80 Ghz for hours. "scaling_max_freq" and "scaling_min_freq" are giving same thing : 2801000

Comment: How are you watching the CPU speed?

Comment: i have gnome cpufreq indicator and its showing the speed. I turned to mate desktop and check for it with mate indicator too. Both says 2.80Ghz. Cpu starting ondemand but after few seconds, its turning to performance mode.

Comment: What does `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` output?

Comment: It's ondemand now because i changed with indicator-cpufreq. But it's not effect my cpu speed. Still 2.80ghz. When i run command `cpufreq-info` there is a part as "current policy" and it says 
`current policy: frequency should be within 2.80 GHz and 2.80 GHz.
                  The governor "conservative" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.`

Comment: When you set scaling_min what value did you use, and was it in, `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies`

Comment: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
2801000` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
2801000` both same

Comment: Well, if you set your scaling mine to 2.8ghz, then it wouldn't scale any lower...

Comment: I didn't set anything. It was working fine yesterday.

Comment: What CPU are you using, if its Intel, cpu-freq doesn't work on that, it uses intel_pstate.

Comment: i think this problem not about intel-pstate. i have settings intel_pstate=disable and cpufreq was working well until this morning

Comment: @bc2946088 hey brother, will you give a new solution? you were almost fixed. what should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with [these steps.](https://www.pantz.org/software/cpufreq/usingcpufreqonlinux.html)

> In K/X/Ubuntu or another Debian-based machine you might just try to
>   install cpufrequtils (`sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils`) to get
>   frequency scaling working. If that does for you then you don't need to
>   go through the parts of finding and loading the correct modules below.
>   Just skip to the section on configuring the scaling governor.
>
> ### Kernel version
>
> Make sure your kernel version is at least 2.6.12 to make use of all
>   the possible governors that will be mentioned. All of the frequency
>   scaling will be done with kernel modules and not user space governors.
>
> ### Enable support in your BIOS
>
> Enter your BIOS and make sure Cool'n'Quiet (AMD) or SpeedStep (Intel)
>   is enabled for you CPU. Some BIOS's may not have an option for either.
>   If you don't find the option it is probably enabled by default.
>   Unfortunately your BIOS may have the option but it is listed as
>   another name altogether. If that is the case check your BIOS's manual
>   for more information.
>
> ### Remove any userspace CPU scaling programs
>
> There are some userspace programs that can be run to scale the
>   processors frequency. We will be scaling the CPU with the kernel so we
>   don't need these. So if you have any we are going remove them now. You
>   may want to look into these as they can be helpful in certain
>   situations. This article will deal with just using the kernel modules
>   to scale.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove powernowd cpudyn cpufreqd powersaved speedfreqd
> ```
>
> ### Install the module for your CPU
>
> When you installed your system there is a very good chance your CPU
>   was detected by default and the module you need for for scaling is
>   already running. Below is a command that will help you identify what
>   type of processor(s) you have.
>
> ```
> cat /proc/cpuinfo
> ```
>
> After you know this then you will know what kernel module you will
>   need to load for it. Here is the command to see what kernel modules
>   are loaded.
>
> ```
> lsmod
> ```
>
> Below are CPU descriptions and the commands used to load the kernel
>   modules based on what processor you have. Look at the output from
>   lsmod above and use the modules names after the word "modprobe" below
>   to see if you already have a module loaded. If you do then just move
>   on to the next step. If not then use the CPU info you found and figure
>   out which module you need to load. Then run the command to load it.
>
> CPU: PIII-M or P4 without est. 2 module types for this.
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe speedstep-ich
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe speedstep-smi
> ```
>
> CPU: Intel Core Duo, Intel Core2 Duo or Quad, or Intel Pentium M. This
>   has been merged into the acpi-cpufreq module in later kernels.
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe speedstep-centrino
> ```
>
> CPU: Intel Celeron, Xeon, and Pentium 4 processors
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe p4_clockmod
> ```
>
> CPU: AMD K6. Socket Type: Socket 7
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe powernow-k6
> ```
>
> CPU: AMD Sempron/Athlon/MP ( K7 ). Socket Types: A, Slot A.
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe powernow-k7
> ```
>
> CPU: AMD Duron/Sempron/Athlon/Opteron 64 ( K8 ). Socket Types: 754,
>   939, 940, S1 ( 638 ), AM2 ( 940 ), F ( 1207 ).
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe powernow-k8
> ```
>
> CPU: VIA CentaurHauls* or Transmeta GenuineTMx86*
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe longhaul
> ```
>
> As a last resort if any of these don't work you can try the generic
>   one for ACPI. More drivers are getting moved to this module in later
>   kernels like speedstep-centrino after 2.6.20.
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe acpi-cpufreq
> ```
>
> ### Inserting the scaling modules
>
> Now that the CPU frequency module is loaded we can now insert the
>   scaling modules. To see which scaling modules you have a available you
>   can use this command (using a Bash shell).
>
> ```
> ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/cpufreq
> ```
>
> If you have these modules then they may already be running. To check
>   if they are try the following command.
>
> ```
> lsmod | grep freq
> ```
>
> If you see most or all of modules that where listed in the cpufreq
>   directory then your done. Move on to the next section. If not here are
>   the commands to load the modules.
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe cpufreq_conservative cpufreq_ondemand cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_stats cpufreq_userspace freq_table
> ```
>
> Now that they are loaded you will want to load them on boot. To do
>   this on a Debian based system like K/X/Ubuntu put the following lines
>   in the /etc/modules file. You will have to check on where to put them
>   on other distros like RedHat (/etc/modules.conf?). Remember to put the
>   name of your CPU's module (you found above) in here also so it loads
>   on boot. That is only if it is not loaded on boot. If you did not find
>   it with lsmod when you first looked then it did not load
>   automatically.
>
> ```
> cpufreq_conservative
> cpufreq_ondemand
> cpufreq_powersave
> cpufreq_stats
> cpufreq_userspace
> freq_table
> ```
>
> ### Configuring the scaling modules
>
> Now that they are loaded we can configure the governor. First you have
>   to choose the governor you want to use. Below is a list the governors
>   and how each works. You can decide which one you fits your needs best.
>   If the module for a governor is loaded then you can use it. Remember
>   you can see what modules are loaded with the lsmod command. Commands
>   are done with sudo below like in K/X/Ubuntu world. You can switch to
>   root and run the same commands just without the sudo sh -c " " if you
>   like.
>
> To show the available governors you can use.
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
> ```
>
> Ondemand governor - sets the CPU frequency depending on the current
>   usage. To do this the CPU must have the capability to switch the
>   frequency very quickly. This would be good for systems that do a lot
>   of work (high load) for a short periods of time and then don't do much
>   (low load) the rest of the time.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo ondemand > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
> ```
>
> #### Ondemand governor configuration options
>
> sampling_rate - This is measured in microseconds (one millionth of a
>   second). This is how often you want the kernel to look at the CPU
>   usage and to make decisions on what to do about the frequency.
>   Typically this is set to values of around '10000' or more. If you
>   wanted to set the sampling rate to 1 second you would set it to
>   1000000 like in the following example.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 1000000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/sampling_rate"
> ```
>
> show_sampling_rate_(min|max) - This is minimum and maximum sampling
>   rates available that you may set 'sampling_rate' to. I believe in
>   microseconds also. I've seen discussion on getting rid of this in
>   later kernels don't count on it being there in the future. To see both
>   just do the following.
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/sampling_rate_min  
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand  /sampling_rate_max
> ```
>
> up_threshold - This defines what the average CPU usage between the
>   samplings of 'sampling_rate' needs to be for the kernel to make a
>   decision on whether or not it should increase the frequency. For
>   example when it is set to its default value of '80' it means that
>   between the checking intervals the CPU needs to be on average more
>   than 80% in use to then decide that the CPU frequency needs to be
>   increased. To set this to something lower like 20% you would do the
>   following.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 20 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/up_threshold"
> ```
>
> ignore_nice_load - This parameter takes a value of '0' or '1'. When
>   set to '0' (its default), all processes are counted towards the 'cpu
>   utilization' value. When set to '1', the processes that are run with a
>   'nice' value will not count (and thus be ignored) in the overall usage
>   calculation. This is useful if you are running a CPU intensive
>   calculation on your laptop that you do not care how long it takes to
>   complete as you can 'nice' it and prevent it from taking part in the
>   deciding process of whether to increase your CPU frequency. To turn
>   this on do the following.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load"
> ```
>
> Conservative governor - CPU frequency is scaled based on current load
>   of the system. It is similar to ondemand. The difference is that it
>   gracefully increases and decreases the CPU speed rather than jumping
>   to max speed the moment there is any load on the CPU. This would be
>   best used in a battery powered environment.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo conservative > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
> ```
>
> #### Conservative governor configuration options
>
> freq_step - This describes what percentage steps the CPU freq should
>   be increased and decreased smoothly by. By default the CPU frequency
>   will increase in 5% chunks of your maximum CPU frequency. You can
>   change this value to anywhere between 0 and 100 where '0' will
>   effectively lock your CPU at a speed regardless of its load whilst
>   '100' will, in theory, make it behave identically to the "ondemand"
>   governor. For example to have it step up and down in increments of 10%
>   you would do the following.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 10 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/conservative/freq_step"
> ```
>
> down_threshold - This is same as the 'up_threshold' found for the
>   "ondemand" governor but for the opposite direction. For example when
>   set to its default value of '20' it means that if the CPU usage needs
>   to be below 20% between samples to have the frequency decreased. For
>   example to set the down threshold to 30% you would do the following.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 30 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/conservative/down_threshold"
> ```
>
> sampling_rate - same as ondemand. sampling_rate_(min|max) - same as
>   ondemand. up_threshold - same as ondemand. ignore_nice_load - same as
>   ondemand.
>
> Performance governor - CPU runs at max frequency regardless of load.
>   This module might not be listed in the running modules but is still
>   available. My guess is it is built into the kernel for K/X/Ubuntu.
>   Yours may be the same way.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
> ```
>
> Powersave governor - CPU runs at min frequency regardless of load.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
> ```
>
> ### Cpufreq stats about your CPU
>
> The cpufreq module lists stats about your CPU. These will help you
>   find out things like the current frequency of your processor or what
>   available frequencies your CPU can scale to. Check them out below.
>
> cpuinfo_cur_freq - Show the current frequency of your CPU(s). You can
>   also find this out by doing a "cat /proc/cpuinfo".
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
> ```
>
> cpuinfo_max_freq - Show the maximum frequency your CPU(s) can scale
>   to.
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
> ```
>
> cpuinfo_min_freq - Show the minimum frequency your CPU(s) can scale
>   to.
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
> ```
>
> scaling_available_frequencies - Show all the available frequencies
>   your CPU(s) can scale to.
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
> ```
>
> scaling_cur_freq - Show the available frequency your CPU(s) are scaled
>   to currently.
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
> ```
>
> scaling_driver - Show the cpufreq driver the CPU(s) are using.
>
> ```
> sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
> ```
>
> scaling_max_freq - Set the maximum frequency your CPU(s) are allowed
>   to scale to. Look at the output from scaling_available_frequencies
>   above. Then you can pick one of those numbers (frequencies) to set to
>   be the maximum frequency the CPU(s) will be allowed to scale to. For
>   example if your CPU output from scaling_available_frequencies was
>   2000000 1800000 1000000 then you might set this to 1800000. So when
>   the CPU scales it will only go to a max of 1800000 and not 2000000. An
>   example on how to set this would be the following.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 1800000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq"
> ```
>
> scaling_min_freq - Same as scaling_max_freq but setting a value that
>   will not allow the CPU(s) to go below. For example.
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 1800000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq"
> ```
>
> ### Keeping any of your settings for cpufreq on reboot
>
> Since all the settings we have been doing are in the /sys virtual file
>   system they will not be saved after a reboot. You can go about setting
>   these on reboot a few ways.
>
> The first way is to put the lines you have been executing in
>   /etc/rc.local. Since root executes rc.local on boot you don't need to
>   sudo before each line. Your rc.local could look like the following
>   example which sets the ondemand governor and the up_threshold to 20%.
>   Don't forget to make sure the module for your CPU and the cpufreq
>   scaling modules are set to load on boot also.
>
> ```
> echo ondemand > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  
> echo 20 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/up_threshold
> ```
>
> The second way to keep your settings on reboot is to install
>   sysfsutils (`sudo apt-get install sysfsutils`). Then you could add the
>   following lines to /etc/sysfs.conf which do the same thing as in the
>   `/etc/rc.conf` example.
>
> ```
> devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor=ondemand   
> devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/up_threshold=20
> ```

Comment: Glad you got it!  The change in init.d to systemd changed to upstart scripts, so there are probably better methods to put in writing for people to follow now.  I didn't want to make an example of how to do it unless it was revised for 2016.  Either way, I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: I appreciate your effort for help me. Thank you again !