# Poor battery life and performance due to incorrect CPU frequency scaling

Tags: power-management, battery, cpu

`lscpu` shows a minimum CPU speed of 1600MHz, rather than 400MHz as the actual minimum. This is absolutely killing my battery life (I get about 2-3 hours rather than the 8-10 I get under Windows on the same hardware) and causing the fan to run constantly.

How do I change the minimum CPU scaling speed?

This is on 18.04 x86_64 - Specific hardware is a HP Envy x360 13" Ryzen 7

```
affected_cpus                  0
bios_limit                     2200000
cpb                            0
cpuinfo_cur_freq               1600000
cpuinfo_max_freq               2200000
cpuinfo_min_freq               1600000
cpuinfo_transition_latency     0
freqdomain_cpus                0 1
related_cpus                   0
scaling_available_frequencies  2200000 1700000 1600000
scaling_available_governors    conservative ondemand userspace powersave perform                    ance schedutil
scaling_cur_freq               1439222
scaling_driver                 acpi-cpufreq
scaling_governor               powersave
scaling_max_freq               2200000
scaling_min_freq               1600000
scaling_setspeed               <unsupported>
stats
```

Edit: This appears to be a broad failure to handle frequency scaling. The frequency isn't increasing under load either. The frequency seems to randomly shift around irrespective of the system load.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from these two commands: `CPU0_DIR=/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq` to set variable. Then use: `paste <(ls $CPU0_DIR) <(cat $CPU0_DIR/*) | column -s $'\t' -t`. Now copy and paste the output into your question. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix done - as an aside I have observed the CPU frequency occasionally dropping to sub-1ghz speeds but it doesn't seem to particularly correlate with system load, it happens randomly and for short periods of time.

Comment: Has there been any progress on the problem?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, the issue hasn't changed after the latest BIOS and various package updates that have occurred since.

Comment: You can try the following `echo 400000 | sudo tee > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` but I'm not sure if it will override the governor.

Comment: Some new developments: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057710/change-min-and-max-cpu-frequency/1057727#1057727 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141157/cpu-governor-changes-automatically-to-performance-under-load

Answer (score 2):

### Update: Try `linux-cpupower`

I found this Q&A that may be of help: [Is it possible to set a *constant* lowest CPU frequency under the modern PSTATE driver?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424602/is-it-possible-to-set-a-constant-lowest-cpu-frequency-under-the-modern-pstate)

Summary of the answer:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-cpupower
```

Then:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
sudo cpupower frequency-set -d 400MHz
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 3100MHz
```

As mentioned elsewhere I don't have an AMD processor and cannot test this for you...

---

I've been thinking of purchasing a Ryzen based system based upon leading-edge developments but I am still Intel platform based.

`cpufrequtils` comes up often on this site and it is designed for your AMD platform. From this [Debian Article](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling) (Debian is the father of Ubuntu) install the AMD CPU utilities using:

```
sudo apt install cpufrequtils
```

Pay close attention to removing or overriding other governor utilities such as `laptop-mode-tools`.

If you have any questions post a comment below and I'll try my best to assist with my limited knowledge of AMD platform.

Additionally, here is a detailed report from another user in Ask Ubuntu: [CPU frequency scaling stuck 2.80 Ghz and it's not going down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783183/cpu-frequency-scaling-stuck-2-80-ghz-and-its-not-going-down)

Comment: Cpufrequtils is already installed, no other governors are installed.

Comment: As reported here removing cpufrequtils solved the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141157/cpu-governor-changes-automatically-to-performance-under-load